# Importing for loop to skip data file not exist

Tags: python

I have about 500 Excel files in the format: data_1, data_2 ... data_500

However, not all file are there. File like data_3 is not in the folder.

I want to import all available data into dataframe.

However, the my code below will stop when it hit a name of file not in the list, say data_3

Can you please help me to skip these record?

Thank you,

HN

```
for i in range(500):
    filename='data_'+ str(i) + 'xlsx'
    output = pd.read_excel('PATH' + filename)
```

THE KEY IS CHECK IN FULL PATH IN glob.glob

```
import glob
for i in xlx_file_list:
    filename = 'Excel_Sample' + str(i) + '.xlsx'                    #; print(filename)
    full_path = 'D:\Python...\\' + filename    #; print(full_path)

    if full_path not in glob.glob('D:\Python...\*'):
        print(filename, ' not in folder')
        continue
    outfile = pd.read_excel(full_path, sheet_name='data_sheet')
    print(outfile)
```

Comment: Handle the error that you're encountering?

Comment: Either use some `try/except` construct or list the files beforehand.

Comment: Take a look at the glob module. `glob.glob('PATH'+'data_*.xlsx')` will return a list containing all files named after the format "data_[whatever].xlsx"

Comment: Thank you, glob.glob is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Hi in your sample probably PATH is a variable, not a string, 'PATH'+filename cannot  work.
i suggest to use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to compose file path, don't use string composition for this.

There are two way to solve this problem:

Generate all names and see if the file exists:

```
import os
for i in range(500):
    filename='data_'+ str(i) + 'xlsx'
    if os.path.exists(filename)
        output = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

or generate only the correct filename list:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('data_*.xlsx'):
    output = pd.read_excel(filename)
```